# while loop to count occur times

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, counter

I have two list `F` and `N`, and I need to use `while` loop function to count how often each element of `F` occurs within `N`. here is my lists:

```
F = [4,7,2] 
N = [2,5,4,2,5,9,3,2,3,7,3,4]
```

I hope to get the result like this:

```
4 occurs in N 2 times
7 occurs in N 1 times
2 occurs in N 3 times
```

here is my code:

```
index = 0
while index < len(N):
    value = N[index]
    print (value)
    index = index +1
else:
     print(index, "occurs in N", value, "times")
print()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use an if statement to see when N(index) == element of F and count how many times that if statement is True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = [4, 7, 2]
n = [2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 3, 4]

index1 = 0

while index1 < len(f):
    value = f[index1]
    count = 0
    index2 = 0
    while index2 < len(n):
        if n[index2] == value:
            count += 1
        index2 += 1
    print(value, "occurs in N", count, "times")
    index1 += 1
```

This is a solution with only while loops, I would use a Counter as in the answer above. Why do you need to use a while loop?

Comment: Why use a second while loop and not just `n.count(value)`?

Comment: As I understand her question, she is only allowed to use while loops, n.count(value) would be better indeed. @Prof

Answer (score 4):

You can simpy use a `Counter` and then use use lookups:

```
from collections import Counter

ncount = Counter(N)

for f in F:
    print(f,"occurs in N",ncount[f],"times")
```

This will result in time complexity *O(|F|+|N|)* (given dictionary lookups happen in *O(1)*, which is nearly always the case).

You can turn the `for` loop into a while loop as follows:

```
i = 0
while i < len(F):
    f = F[i]
    print(f,"occurs in N",ncount[f],"times")
    i += 1
```

But it is better to use a `for` loop since with a `for` loop progression, etc. is guaranteed (for instance you do not have to think about incrementing `i`).

Given you are not allowed to use a `Counter`, you can do the counting yourself, for instance by using list comprehension:

```
i = 0
while i < len(F):
    f = F[i]
    print(f,"occurs in N",len([1 for x in N if x == f]),"times")
```

or by using `sum`:

```
i = 0
while i < len(F):
    f = F[i]
    print(f,"occurs in N",sum(x == f for x in N),"times")
```

Or you can use the `.count()` function of a list:

```
i = 0
while i < len(F):
    f = F[i]
    print(f,"occurs in N",N.count(f),"times")
```

Comment: Thanks @ WIllem Van Onsem, but we are required to use while loop instead of for loop. I am stuck on how to use while loop to write the code...

Comment: @Sophie: are you allowed to use  a `Counter`?

Comment: we are not allowed to use Counter, that's why I am so confused on this question